# Why different pages report different number of mempool transactions?

Tags: transactions, mempool

I see different reports of transactions in mempool. From 35k (statoshi.info) over 170k (blockchain.info) to 215k (bitaps.com). All pages claim to report in realtime. Why is that? The difference is so big that it can not be caused by sync delays..